# Joomla: не меняется страница после изменение стиля

Tags: html, css, css3, joomla, joomla3

Суть проблемы такова: необходимо в стилях чуть-чуть подкрутить отступы активного пункта drop-down menu. Я смотрю в firebug где находится стиль, который за это отвечает, иду по пути в FTP и там меняю необходимые значения, но ничего совершенно не меняется, все стили остаются прежними, а firebug показывает старые значения, словно они никогда и не менялись.

шаблон: yoo_balance
сам сайт: 100-89.ru
Смотрите на нажатый пункт верхнего меню, в нем необходимо увеличить отступы слева и справа.

Comment: Привет Vsaverin. 
Чтобы убедиться, что это именно тот файл (Даже, если закэширован), переименуй его. 
Далее, если пропал стиль полностью - тогда возвращай имя и копай в сторону кэширования, либо файл типа json.блабла, или отдельные папки с кэшем. 

Если же у тебя не пропал стиль после изменения имени - значит это не тот файл, или данные css меняются уже в js на выходе. 

Так сходу сложно сказать.

Comment: Проблема решена, необходимо было удалить кэш в настройках самого движка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть закэшировалось и надо обновить кэш? Я работаю с Opencart, а не Joomla, к сожалению не сведущ в её настройках и возможностях, просто предлагаю вариант, так как очень часто такие случаи происходят и с Opencart.